# how to create a 32bit UEFI bootable recovery flash drive from within windows 10 64bit?

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, recovery-disk

I have windows 10 64bit version but I need a bootable recovery drive for a 32bit UEFI environment because my other computer has a 32bit UEFI system.
How can I create a 32 bit UEFI bootable usb flash drive as a recovery disk from my current windows 10 64bit?

Is there any legal solution? any scripts for that?

Comment: Not possible. Recovery drive is just that "recovery". Your attempt may count as piracy. Also bit cannot be changed trivially

Comment: Download 32bit iso and make it bootable with Rufus.

Comment: The WinRE on a Windows ISO contains the same environment that th Recovery Media uses.